# Redundant servers for Silverlight 4.0 App

Tags: sql-server-2008, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

In Future, I will have a Silverlight 4.0 application that will run on a server an will be access by browser and as Out-of-Browser App. With RIA-Services I conect to a SQL Server 2008 and load data. 
Does anyone know whether it is possible to have a second database-server and if Server one is down, the application noticed that. So the application works with the second server further.
The structure of the servers and the kind of synchronice of the servers is no matter at the moment. Only the question of feasibility is important and how I can do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use database mirroring to provide a failover for the SQL server. This link provides more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188712.aspx).

I have used this as I couldn't justify clustering, the only development effort I had to do extra was to retry on failure which typically meant that the connection was moving from the primary database server to the mirror.

The application does not have any knowledge of the database setup, the connection string holds all the information to make this work.

Hope this helps.